# Swapping variables in a class without using a temporary variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code. It's a standard Binary Tree class.

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t
```

In the else clause, could I remove the t variable and simply do this:

```
BinaryTree(newNode).leftChild, self.leftChild = self.leftChild, BinaryTree(newNode)
```

Would this work? It looks like I'm calling the BinaryTree class twice, would that create two different instances?

Comment: you could take the left/right child as optional arguments to `__init__`, then you could do `self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode, leftChild=self.leftChild)` (that would also save you the trouble of explicitly checking `if self.leftChild==None`

Comment: To answer your question, yes. You would end up creating two different instances.

Comment: You would not have any reference to the newly created object on the left side. It would be garbage collected after that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately you need to be able to keep track of the newly created `BinaryTree` instance and the previous `self.leftChild` value at the same time as you have it written, using simultaneous assignments will not work in this scenario.

However if you allowed the `leftChild` to be specified in the constructor then the new `BinaryTree` instance could be created with `self.leftChild` right away:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj, leftnode=None, rightnode=None):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.leftChild = leftnode
        self.rightChild = rightnode

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        #if self.leftChild == None: pass leftnode=None to constructor.
        # which is the same as passing leftnode=self.leftChild
        self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode, leftnode = self.leftChild)
```

This way the newly created node has its own `leftChild` attribute set upon initialization so there is no need to manually do it in `insertLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

In a `BinaryTree` you must create a temporary variable, because use Object. if are a integer could be:

```
a = 5
b = 3
a += b # a = 8
b = a - b # b = 5
a -= b # a = 3
print(a)
>>3
print(b)
>>5
```